# HERE Android SDK AudioPlayerDelegate does not work

Tags: android, sdk, here-api

I created a AudioPlayerDelegate  to play navigation text via my audio player, but the function playText() never get called during navigation, while another function playFiles() get called.

Below is the code snippet:

```
private class MyAudioPlayerDelegate implements AudioPlayerDelegate {

        @Override
        public boolean playText(String s) {

            TTSController.getInstance(HEREMapActivity.this).playText(s);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean playFiles(String[] strings) {
            Log.d("voice", strings.toString());
            return true;
        }
    }


  if (myAudioPlayerDelegate == null) {
            myAudioPlayerDelegate = new MyAudioPlayerDelegate();
   }
        navigationManager.getAudioPlayer().setDelegate(myAudioPlayerDelegate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are not using a TTS enabled voice skin.  Only TTS skins will callback to the playText() method.

Comment: Thanks David,   I missed to call voicePackage.isTts() while setting up the VoiceSkin of NavigationManager .
                if (voicePackage.isTts()) 
                {
                    id = voicePackage.getId();
                    break;
                }
            }